# Are isometries of $\mathbb{R}$ always differentiable with constant derivate 1 or -1?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show, that if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an isometry, then $f$ is everywhere differentiable. Moreover, either $f'(x)=1$ for all $x$ or $f'(x) = -1$ for all $x$ holds.

I know since $f$ is an isometry, $f$ is continuous. I also know if $f$ is an injective continuous function, then $f$ is monotone. I'm just not sure how to go a few steps farther.

Comment: Try writing the definition of what it means to be differentiable (as the existence of a limit) then see if you can use the most basic property of an isometry (I.e. It's an isometry) to determine something about that limit

Comment: The derivative is $\pm1.$ What is a derivate?

Answer (score 4):

I claim that an isometry $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ is of one of the forms $f(x)=c+x$ or $f(x)=c-x$ for 
some $c\in{\mathbb R}$.

*Proof.* Let $f(0)=:c$. The translation $T_{-c}:\> y\mapsto y-c$ is an isometry. Therefore $g:=T_{-c}\circ f$, i.e., $g(x):=f(x)-c$ is an isometry that fixes $0$. It follows that $g(1)=1$ or $g(1)=-1$. In the second case replace $g$ by $\hat g:=\iota\circ g$, where $\iota$ denotes the reflection in $0$. We now know that $g$ (resp., $\hat g$) keeps both points $0$ and $1$ fixed. Consider now any point $x\in{\mathbb R}$. Then
$$|g(x)|=|g(x)-g(0)|=|x|,\quad |g(x)-1|=|g(x)-g(1)|=|x-1|\ .$$
Squaring gives
$$g^2(x)=x^2,\qquad g^2(x)-2g(x)+1=x^2-2x+1\ ,$$
which allows to conclude that $g(x)=x$. It follows that $f$ assumes one of the given forms.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There are two real numbers whose distance from $f(0)$ is $|x|$.  Their distances from $f(1)$ are not the same...